# How to make JQuery continuously loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please assist with this please? I'm clearly a rookie as this isn't tough but I can't figure it out.  This rotates between 4 background images and all I want to do is have it start over at the first image (loop) and run through the function again.

Really appreciate the help!

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 


$(".wrapper").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)), url(<%= asset_path('bg-1.jpg') %>)"
    );
    setTimeout(function(){
            $(".wrapper").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)), url(<%= asset_path('bg-1.jpg') %>)"
        ).fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).css("background-image", "linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)), url(<%= asset_path('bg-2.jpg') %>)"
            ).fadeIn();
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
                $(".wrapper").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)), url(<%= asset_path('bg-2.jpg') %>)"
            ).fadeOut(function(){
                $(this).css("background-image", "linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)), url(<%= asset_path('bg-3.jpg') %>)"
                ).fadeIn();
            });
            setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".wrapper").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)), url(<%= asset_path('bg-3.jpg') %>)"
                ).fadeOut(function(){
                    $(this).css("background-image", "linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)), url(<%= asset_path('bg-4.jpg') %>)"
                    ).fadeIn();
                });
            }, 3000);
        }, 3000);
    }, 3000);


});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code that should do what you want. You'll need to change the places that I marked to use code specific to your use case. What makes this work is that the images are stored in an array and then you update the index of the next image. The key to starting over at the beginning is the `% 4` which makes it so the possible values are only ever 0, 1, 2, or 3.

EDIT: I also added a way of doing the same thing using setTimeout which is an alternative way to handle the timing that can be safer but also makes the timing work slightly differently in that the timer starts after `.fadeOut` has been called instead of before it.

```js
$(function(){
  /* This is the array you should use
  var images = [
    <%= asset_path('bg-1.jpg') %>,
    <%= asset_path('bg-2.jpg') %>,
    <%= asset_path('bg-3.jpg') %>,
    <%= asset_path('bg-4.jpg') %>;
  */
  // This is just so the demo can work
  var images = ['image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4'];
  
  var nextImageIndex = 1;
  
  // Set first image
  $('.wrapper').text(images[0]); // Adjust this for your use case
  
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.wrapper').fadeOut(function() {
      $(this).text(images[nextImageIndex]); // Adjust this for your use case
      nextImageIndex = (nextImageIndex + 1) % 4;
    }).fadeIn();
  }, 3000);

  /*
   * Here is an example using setTimeout since it can be safer
   * than setInterval. This will not make the image update every
   * 3 seconds though, it will actually update ~3 seconds after
   * you make the call to fadeOut.
   */
  
  var nextImageIndexForTimeout = 1;
  
  function updateImage() {
    $('.wrapper2').fadeOut(function() {
      $(this).text(images[nextImageIndexForTimeout]); // Adjust this for your use case
      nextImageIndexForTimeout = (nextImageIndexForTimeout + 1) % 4;
    }).fadeIn();
    
    setTimeout(updateImage, 3000);
  }
  
  // Set first image
  $('.wrapper2').text(images[0]); // Adjust this for your use case
  
  setTimeout(updateImage, 3000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="wrapper2"></div>
```

Comment: setInterval() is often not recommended for animation, as it counts time from the start of the function execution; so if you have long-running functions being executed the actual animation can be screwy.

Comment: @Paul I guess that depends on if the OP wants this to run every 3 seconds or if they want it to execute 3 seconds after the new image is visible. I assumed based on the way the original was written that it was to run every 3 seconds regardless of the animation. That could be a flawed assumption though.

Comment: Well, not just that.  I've actually had serious performance issues when function calls start getting stacked up behind each other (e.g. a slow render, so the first one's not even done before the next starts), and have seen browsers crash.  Granted, those are extreme cases, but my point is that it's "safer" to use setTimeout since there's no downside to doing so, and only upside.

Comment: If you want to make sure that it is running every 3 seconds regardless of the animation, you will still have the same problem won't you? Because you'll need to set up the next setTimeout call before you start doing the work right? Otherwise, you actually have it happen every 3 seconds plus processing time of the function. I've not done extensive animation work so I may be incorrect there.

Comment: That's almost never what you want, though.  You may think it's what you want, but it really isn't 99% of the time.  I'll grant that it's a different way of thinking of things.

Comment: @rdubya Thanks for this!  I'm still running into a hiccup as the image won't show now--     `var images = [
     "<%= asset_path('bg-1.jpg') %>",
     "<%= asset_path('bg-2.jpg') %>",
     "<%= asset_path('bg-3.jpg') %>",
     "<%= asset_path('bg-4.jpg') %>",
  ];
   
   var nextImageIndex = 1;
   
   // Set first image
   $('.wrapper').css("background-image", "linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)), url(images[0])"
   );`

Answer (score 0):

This is not about making jquery continuously loop, instead what you want is to have an array of image URLs, and take the 'next' one every time the timer fires.  There's a few ways to do this, but since you're already familiar with setTimeout I'll use that.

```
var images = [img0, img1, img2, img3];  // those should be the URLs to your background images

function setNextImage(){
   var image = images.shift(); // image is now the first image in the array.
   images.push(image); // place that one back on the end of the array.
   $(".wrapper").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)), url("+image+")"
    );
   setTimeout(setNextImage, 3000);
};

$(function(){ 
  setNextImage();
});
```